# How to get the id of the channel after creating it

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm creating a bot that makes a Temporary channels and i have a problem, How can i get the id of the channel after creating it directly and assigning it to a variable?

this is my code:

```
public void onGuildVoiceJoin(GuildVoiceJoinEvent event) {

            if(event.getChannelJoined().getIdLong() == 703255821508673546L) {
            event.getGuild().getCategoryById("704418165710651492").createVoiceChannel("%s".format("channel" + event.getMember().getEffectiveName())).addPermissionOverride(event.getMember().getGuild().getPublicRole(), null, EnumSet.of(Permission.VOICE_CONNECT, Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL)).addMemberPermissionOverride(event.getMember().getIdLong(), EnumSet.of(Permission.MANAGE_CHANNEL, Permission.VOICE_CONNECT, Permission.MANAGE_PERMISSIONS, Permission.VOICE_MOVE_OTHERS), null).queue();
            event.getGuild().getCategoryById("704418165710651492").createTextChannel("%s".format("channel" + event.getMember().getEffectiveName())).queue();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please use variables in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `queue()` is an async operation you have to use the callback

```java
category.createVoiceChannel(name)
        .addPermissionOverride(role, allowRole, denyRole)
        .addPermissionOverride(member, allowMember, denyMember)
        .queue(channel -> {
            System.out.println("ID for voice channel: " + channel.getId());
        });
```

See [javadoc](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#queue(java.util.function.Consumer)) and [wiki](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7%29-Using-RestAction#using-queue).

Answer (score 0):

You could go through the list of created channels afterwards using these Cateogry methods:

```
    /**
 * All {@link net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel TextChannels}
 * listed for this Category
 *
 * @return Immutable list of all child TextChannels
 */
@Nonnull
List<TextChannel> getTextChannels();

/**
 * All {@link net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.VoiceChannel VoiceChannels}
 * listed for this Category
 *
 * @return Immutable list of all child VoiceChannels
 */
@Nonnull
List<VoiceChannel> getVoiceChannels();
```

https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Category.java

Though as stated already you cannot guarantee that these channels have been created yet as queue is an asynchronous method.